# Ubuntu cloud image OVA in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, cloud, cloud-init

Ubuntu Cloud Images now provides a downloadable .ova dedicated to VMWare/Virtualbox. While these images are easily importable into Virtualbox I'm struggling to set up a valid users account on the actual system.

All resources I found on the internet are referring to .img files you can download from Ubuntu Cloud Images repository.

How can I gain access to the focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova I download from [Ubuntu Cloud Images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/20210224/)? Is there a default password? Cloud init? Anything else?

Comment: Did you not already ask this?

Comment: I did not. I just found the ova option today

Comment: Here is the updated link -- to the current image: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/current/